# Search specific text with DOM XPath

Tags: xpath, simple-html-dom, web-crawler

I have been trying to crawl a website pages and search for specific text using simple html dom and XPath. I have get all the links from website and trying to crawl that links and search text on all pages. The text that i want to search is within html span tag.
But no output is shown.

whats going wrong ?

here is my code

```
<?php
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
set_time_limit(0);

$path='http://www.barringtonsports.com';

$html = file_get_contents($path);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

for($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++ ){
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    $nurl = $path.$url;

    $html1 = file_get_contents($nurl);
    $dom1 = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom1->loadHTML($html1);

    $xpath1 = new DOMXPath($dom1);
    $name = $xpath1->evaluate("//span[contains(.,'Asics Gel Netburner 15 Netball      Shoes')]");

    if($name)
        echo"text found";
}   
?>
```

I just want to check the whether text "Asics Gel Netburner 15 Netball Shoes" exist in any page of the website www.barringtonsports.com or not.

Answer (score 0):

You're querying a lot of web-pages interactively. It takes more time than your server is allowed to use for generating pages.

You can execute this script from command-line to avoid timeouts or you can try to configure PHP and WebServer so they give more time to the script (you can ask on https://serverfault.com/ how to do this)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off you are mixing Simple HTML DOM and DOM Document. Just use one or the other. Since this is in the simple-html-dom tag start with this from the command line:

```
<?php
require_once("./simple_html_dom.php");          # simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net to use     manual
$path="http://www.barringtonsports.com";
$html = file_get_html($path);
foreach ($html->find('a') as $anchor) {
    $url = $anchor->href;
    echo "Found link to " . $url . "\n";
    # now see if the link is relative, absolute, or even on another site...
    $checkhtml = file_get_html($url);
    # now you can parse that link for stuff too.
}
?>
```

But really, that website has a search form, why not just send it a query instead and read the results?